# Displaying the group header in a grouped ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Display the group header in a `ListView` other than by the sort key.

Hello, I am developing a UWP application for Windows 10 mobile.
I have a `ListView` with items from a SQLite database. Each item belongs to a category, and the `ListView` is grouped by category. In the display, the header of the groups is the name of the category, and these categories are sorted in alphabetical order.
The main elements of the XAML code are:

```
<ListView x:Name="listBoxobj" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsource}}"
    BorderBrush="#FF141EE4" 
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    SelectionMode="None"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    RightTapped="listBoxobj_RightTapped"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Name}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="NameTxt" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding NomArt}" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="QteArtTxt" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding QuantArt}" FontSize="20" Foreground="DarkGray" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="UniteMesureTxt" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UnitArt}" FontSize="20" Foreground="DarkGray" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="btnPanier" Grid.Column="1" Height="35" Width="35" Tag="{Binding}" Click="btnPanier_Click">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/icone_caddie_40x40.png" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                        </ImageBrush>
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock x:Name="NoteTxt" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding NoteArt}" FontSize="16" Foreground="DarkGray" FontStyle="Italic"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="CadetBlue" FontSize="18" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.Resources>
        <MenuFlyout x:Name="MenuFlyoutContext" x:Key="FlyoutBaseKey">
            <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="MFSubMenu1" x:Uid="MenuFlyoutModif" Click="MFSubMenu1_Click"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="MFSubMenu2" x:Uid="MenuFlyoutDelete" Click="MFSubMenu2_Click"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="FlyoutBaseKey"/>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</ListView>
```

Here is the code behind to display the ListView :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
        currentListeAchat = e.Parameter as string;
        textBlock.Text = resourceLoader.GetString("PanierTitre") + " " + currentListeAchat;
        //
        Achats = new ObservableCollection<Achat>();
        AchatsIn = new ObservableCollection<Achat>();
        //
        DB_PanierList = dbpaniers.GetAllPaniers();
        var query = DB_PanierList.Where(x => x.NomListe == currentListeAchat & x.InOut == "Out");
        //
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            string nomart = item.Name;
            string quantart = item.QteArt;
            string noteart = item.Note;
            string catart = item.NomCat;
            int catorder = item.OrdreCat; 
            string unitart = item.UniteMesure;
            string inout = item.InOut;
            Achats.Add(new Achat()
            {
                NomArt = nomart,
                QuantArt = quantart,
                NoteArt = noteart,
                CatArt = catart,
                CatOrder = catorder,
                UnitArt = unitart,
                InOut = inout
            });
        }
        //
        _groupingCollection = new ObservableGroupingCollection<string, Achat>(Achats);
        _groupingCollection.ArrangeItems(new CatSorter(), (x => x.CatOrder.ToString()));
        GroupedAchats = _groupingCollection.Items;
        cvsource.Source = GroupedAchats;
        //
        //
        var queryin = DB_PanierList.Where(x => x.NomListe == currentListeAchat & x.InOut == "In");
        //
        foreach (var item in queryin)
        {
            string nomart = item.Name;
            string quantart = item.QteArt;
            string noteart = item.Note;
            string catart = item.NomCat;
            int catorder = item.OrdreCat;
            string unitart = item.UniteMesure;
            string inout = item.InOut;
            AchatsIn.Add(new Achat()
            {
                NomArt = nomart,
                QuantArt = quantart,
                NoteArt = noteart,
                CatArt = catart,
                CatOrder = catorder,
                UnitArt = unitart,
                InOut = inout
            });
        }
        //
        _groupingCollectionIn = new ObservableGroupingCollection<string, Achat>(AchatsIn);
        _groupingCollectionIn.ArrangeItems(new CatSorter(), (x => x.CatArt));
        GroupedAchatsIn = _groupingCollectionIn.Items;
        cvsourceIn.Source = GroupedAchatsIn;
        //
        // Register for hardware and software back request from the system
        SystemNavigationManager systemNavigationManager = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
        systemNavigationManager.BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
    }
```

And the class ObservableGroupingCollection :

```
public class ObservableGroupingCollection<K, T> where K : IComparable
{
    public ObservableGroupingCollection(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
    {
        _rootCollection = collection;
        _rootCollection.CollectionChanged += _rootCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    ObservableCollection<T> _rootCollection;
    private void _rootCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    ObservableCollection<Grouping<K, T>> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<Grouping<K, T>> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    IComparer<T> _sortOrder;
    Func<T, K> _groupFunction;

    public void ArrangeItems(IComparer<T> sortorder, Func<T, K> group)
    {
        _sortOrder = sortorder;
        _groupFunction = group;

        var temp = _rootCollection
            .OrderBy(i => i, _sortOrder)
            .GroupBy(_groupFunction)
            .ToList()
            .Select(g => new Grouping<K, T>(g.Key, g));

        _items = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<K, T>>(temp);

    }

    private void HandleCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            var item = (T)(e.NewItems[0]);
            var value = _groupFunction.Invoke(item);

            // find matching group if exists
            var existingGroup = _items.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key.Equals(value));

            if (existingGroup == null)
            {
                var newlist = new List<T>();
                newlist.Add(item);

                // find first group where Key is greater than this key
                var insertBefore = _items.FirstOrDefault(g => ((g.Key).CompareTo(value)) > 0);
                if (insertBefore == null)
                {
                    // not found - add new group to end of list
                    _items.Add(new Grouping<K, T>(value, newlist));
                }
                else
                {
                    // insert new group at this index
                    _items.Insert(_items.IndexOf(insertBefore), new Grouping<K, T>(value, newlist));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // find index to insert new item in existing group
                int index = existingGroup.ToList().BinarySearch(item, _sortOrder);
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    existingGroup.Insert(~index, item);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            var item = (T)(e.OldItems[0]);
            var value = _groupFunction.Invoke(item);

            var existingGroup = _items.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key.Equals(value));

            if (existingGroup != null)
            {
                // find existing item and remove
                var targetIndex = existingGroup.IndexOf(item);
                existingGroup.RemoveAt(targetIndex);

                // remove group if zero items
                if (existingGroup.Count == 0)
                {
                    _items.Remove(existingGroup);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

As can be seen, the header is generated classically by the line:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="CadetBlue" FontSize="18" />
```

I would like the user to be able to order the categories according to his choice. So I added an `OrderCat` (int) field, which numbers the categories from 1 to (number of categories). In my code behind, I group the `ListView` not on the `Category` field, but on `OrderCat`, and it works well (the groups appear in the chosen order, not in alphabetical order). Only problem because of the `{Binding Key}`, the header displays the number (`OdreCat`), not the name of the category. How to display the name corresponding to the number?

Can someone help me?

Comment: I can't get OrderCat in your code. could you share mini sample that could reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Give a look at Semantic Zoom component, I believe it can be really helpful to your solution.
Basicaly you need to configure the zoom in and zoom out display, for the zoom out you can show only the categories and for the zoom in you can show the grouped list.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/semantic-zoom

Comment: Hello Nico, Sorry for the missing code, but the new site editing rules did not allow me to post it. I will retry again, including the code behind.

Comment: For Ghuilherme : the Semantic Zoom is not adapted in my case, because when a user delete an item in the list, I must refresh all the list for reflecting the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for all those who tried to help me, but it was impossible for me to answer, because I did not provide an important element: the CatSorter class.
That's where the change had to be made. Here it is before modification:

```
public class CatSorter : Comparer<Achat>
{
    public override int Compare(Achat x, Achat y)
    {
        int result = x.CatArt.CompareTo(y.CatArt);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result = x.CatOrder.CompareTo(y.CatOrder);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return x.NomArt.CompareTo(y.NomArt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And after modification:

```
public class CatSorter : Comparer<Achat>
{
    public override int Compare(Achat x, Achat y)
    {
        int result = x.CatOrder.CompareTo(y.CatOrder);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result = x.CatArt.CompareTo(y.CatArt);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return x.NomArt.CompareTo(y.NomArt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the method that reads and groups the Listview, it is necessary to group the list by the name of the article (CatArt) and not by the ranking number (CatOrder).
Here is the line to rectify:

```
_groupingCollection.ArrangeItems(new CatSorter(), (x => x.CatArt));
```

These modifications being done, the program groups the articles by category, the categories are classified according to the order chosen by the user, and most importantly, it is the name of the category which appears as header of the group, and not the ranking number.
I hope my answer is clear enough.